# Potentially outdated term in the "How do I search?" article

Tags: support, bug, tags, search, help-center

Quote from [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

> `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags you have marked as **favorite**.

How can we mark tags as favorite? I only see "Watch tag" and "Ignore tag". I guess "Watch tag" does the job?

If so, then the document should be updated to "... in tags **you are watching**".

[image]

Comment: Related: ['Favorite Tags' is now 'Tag Watching'](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/289905).